# Loading a form to be edited that has inter-related drop-down lists

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

So my problem is the following: it is easy to get data concerning some record and make it available in a form.

The thing is: part of it is a location (continent, country, city) which is represented by 3 inter-related drop-down lists.

What I get is the browser to stop responding, I need some ideas to come up with a better solution.

Here is a sample of the code with comments on where it stalls, so maybe someone can give me a hint:

```
 // To load the drop-down lists I use similar ajax code as the one shown below in the edit case

 function processRow(command, id) {
    switch(command){

    case 'Delete': {    
        $("#deleteId").val(id);
        $('#deleteEventModal').reveal();
    }
    break;
    case 'Edit': {
        /* Fetch Data to Fill up the form */
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "scripts/fetchEventById.php?eventId=" + encodeURIComponent(id),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                    /* On Successful Posting to server side */
                                // THIS DROP DOWN LOADS AND SETS DB VAL OK
                    loadContinents("#editEventContinents");
                    $("#editEventContinents").val(response.eventData.continentId);           

                     // FROM THIS MOMENT ON IT WILL STALL
                     // last instruction sets continent drop-down with proper value BUT
                     // when fetching the countries for that continent (below)
                     // the continent drop-down value comes empty as if nothing 
                     // was selected
                     // but it was, I visually confirmed that 
                     // after setting it with val() above
                    loadCountries("#editEventContinents", "#editEventCountries", "#editEventCities");
                    $("#editEventCountries").val(response.eventData.countryId);

                   loadCities("#editEventCountries", "#editEventCities");
                   $("#editEventCities").val(response.eventData.cityId);

                   $("#editEventStartDate").val(response.eventData.startDate);
                   $("#editEventEndDate").val(response.eventData.endDate);
                   $("#editEventUserName").val(response.eventData.userName);
                   $("#editEventName").val(response.eventData.eventName);
                   $("#editEventDetails").val(response.eventData.details);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){            
                /* log the error to the console */
                console.log(
                    "The following error occured: " + 
                    textStatus, errorThrown
                );
            }
        });

        // Get the overlay with the form for editing to pop up                              
        $('#editEventModal').reveal();
    }
    break;
    default:
        // oops, something wrong happened
    break;
}
return false;
}

// Here is the load continents function
function loadContinents(continentObj) {     
// fetch continent data

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "scripts/fetchContinents.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        /* On Successful Posting to server side */

        // Add fetched options to the select object responsible for holding the continents list
        $(continentObj).empty(); //clear current available selections
        if( data == "" ){
            $(continentObj).append("<option value=\"\">No continents found</option>");
        }
        else{
            for( i = 0; i < data.id.length; i++ ){
                $(continentObj).append("<option value=\"" + data.id[i]  + "\">" + data.name[i]  + "</option>");
            }
        }

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        /* log the error to the console */
        console.log(
            "The following error occured: " + 
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );

        $(countryObj).append("<option selected value=\"\">Select Continent</option>");

        $("#searchEventError").fadeOut(200);
        $("#searchEventError").fadeIn(200).html("<div class=\"alert-box error\">Something went wrong with the server request, please try again later</div>");
    }
});

return false;
}

// Load Countries
function loadCountries(continentObj, countryObj, cityObj) {
var continentOption = $(continentObj).val();

// clear/reset countries and cities selections
$(countryObj).empty();
$(cityObj).empty().append("<option selected value=\"-1\">Please Select Country First</option>");

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "scripts/fetchCountries.php?continent=" + encodeURIComponent(continentOption),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        /* On Successful Posting to server side */

        // Add fetched options to the select object responsible for holding the countries list
        if( data == "" ){
            $(countryObj).append("<option value=\"0\">No countries found</option>");
        }
        else{
            for( i = 0; i < data.id.length; i++ ){
                $(countryObj).append("<option value=\"" + data.id[i]  + "\">" + data.name[i]  + "</option>");
            }
        }

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        /* log the error to the console */
        console.log(
            "The following error occured: " + 
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );

        $(countryObj).append("<option selected value=\"-1\">Please Select Continent First</option>");

        $("#searchEventError").fadeOut(200);
        $("#searchEventError").fadeIn(200).html("<div class=\"alert-box error\">Something went wrong with the server request, please try again later</div>");

    }
});

return false;
}

// Load Cities
function loadCities(countryObj, cityObj) {
var countryOption = $(countryObj).val();

// clear/reset cities selections
$(cityObj).empty();

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "scripts/fetchCities.php?country=" + encodeURIComponent(countryOption),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        /* On Successful Posting to server side */

        // Add fetched options to the select object responsible for holding the cities list     
        if( data == "" ){
            $(cityObj).append("<option value=\"0\">No cities found</option>");
        }
        else{
            for( i = 0; i < data.id.length; i++ ){
                $(cityObj).append("<option value=\"" + data.id[i]  + "\">" + data.name[i]  + "</option>");
            }
        }

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){            
        /* log the error to the console */
        console.log(
            "The following error occured: " + 
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );

        $(cityObj).append("<option selected value=\"-1\">Please Select Country First</option>");

        $("#searchEventError").fadeOut(200);
        $("#searchEventError").fadeIn(200).html("<div class=\"alert-box error\">Something went wrong with the server request, please try again later</div>");
    }
});

return false;
}
```

Comment: When you say the browser stops responding, do you mean its completely locked up?  You can't type in the address bar and go to another site?  Or do you mean that the Javascript stops processing?

Comment: I mean it looks like the browser gets locked up.

The question now is: why doesn't $("#editEventContinents").val(continentId);  stick as a selected value in the continents option so that it can be used to fetch that continent's countries?

What happens (I found out in the meanwhile) is that the continent parameter is getting empty in the fetch countries querystring. As a consequence the same will happen to cities.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full code.  Except not knowing what loadContinents is doing, this doesn't have anything that jumps out at me as being browser fatal.  Please post the full code and I'll take a look.

Comment: Just included the load continents, countries and cities in there, thanks for having a look, it is starting to get me nuts...

Most likely it will be something stupid, but either way... need fresh ideas.

Comment: I'm primarily trying to figure out what's killing your browser.  Once you stop that, debugging gets easier. :)  By any chance, do you have a change listener on any of these dropdowns?  The only thing I can think of is that you've created an endless loop where you update the dropdown and it kicks off the listener again.

Comment: Hi, yes, there is a change listener. When continents change that should trigger a loadCountries, when countries change it should trigger a loadCities.

But when I use the  $("#editEventContinents").val(response.eventData.continentId); to change the selected continent option, this is not triggering the change listener, that is the reason why after I am calling loadCountries explicitly and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your `loadCountries` is included inside of `processRow`, so event values are coming back and being set, but then loadCountries is coming in and overwriting that value again.

I suggest pulling your country and city data based on the selected values in the inital load, so you don't have to wait multiple times.  Get your event details to include all the countries in the selected continent, all the cities in the selected country, and output that in your event details JSON.

The other thing you can try is nesting your AJAX calls so that each one needs to wait for the next like this (I don't suggest this):

```
function processRow(command, id) {
    console.log('Starting the processing of row #' +id);
    switch(command){

        case 'Delete': {    
            $("#deleteId").val(id);
            $('#deleteEventModal').dialog( "open" );
        }
        break;
        case 'Edit': {
            /* Fetch Data to Fill up the form */    

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "stackAjax.php?Action=Event&eventId=" + encodeURIComponent(id),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    $("#editEventStartDate").val(response.eventData.startDate);
                    $("#editEventEndDate").val(response.eventData.endDate);
                    $("#editEventUserName").val(response.eventData.userName);
                    $("#editEventName").val(response.eventData.eventName);
                    $("#editEventDetails").val(response.eventData.details);
                    $("#editEventContinents").val(response.eventData.continentId);

                    /* On Successful Posting to server side */
                    window.currentContinent = response.eventData.continentId;
                    window.currentCountry = response.eventData.countryId;
                    window.currentCity = response.eventData.cityId;

                    var countryObj = $("#editEventCountries"),
                    cityObj = $("#editEventCities");

                    $(countryObj).empty();
                    $(cityObj).empty().append("<option selected value=\"-1\">Please Select Country First</option>");

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "stackAjax.php?Action=Countries&continent=" + encodeURIComponent(window.currentContinent),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(countryData){
                            /* On Successful Posting to server side */

                            // Add fetched options to the select object responsible for holding the countries list
                            if( countryData == "" ){
                                $(countryObj).append("<option value=\"0\">No countries found</option>");
                            }
                            else{
                                for( i = 0; i < countryData.id.length; i++ ){
                                    $(countryObj).append("<option value=\"" + countryData.id[i]  + "\">" + countryData.name[i]  + "</option>");
                                }
                            }

                            $(cityObj).empty();

                            console.log('about to set the country');        
                            $("#editEventCountries").val(response.eventData.countryId);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "stackAjax.php?Action=Cities&country=" + encodeURIComponent(window.currentCountry),
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function(cityData){
                                    /* On Successful Posting to server side */

                                    // Add fetched options to the select object responsible for holding the cities list     
                                    if( cityData == "" ){
                                        $(cityObj).append("<option value=\"0\">No cities found</option>");
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        for( i = 0; i < cityData.id.length; i++ ){
                                            $(cityObj).append("<option value=\"" + cityData.id[i]  + "\">" + cityData.name[i]  + "</option>");
                                        }
                                    }

                                console.log('about to set the city');       
                                $("#editEventCities").val(response.eventData.cityId);
                                },
                                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){            
                                    /* log the error to the console */
                                    console.log(
                                        "The following error occured: " + 
                                        textStatus, errorThrown
                                    );

                                    $(cityObj).append("<option selected value=\"-1\">Please Select Country First</option>");

                                    $("#searchEventError").fadeOut(200);
                                    $("#searchEventError").fadeIn(200).html("<div class=\"alert-box error\">Something went wrong with the server request, please try again later</div>");
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            /* log the error to the console */
                            console.log(
                                "The following error occured: " + 
                                textStatus, errorThrown
                            );

                            $(countryObj).append("<option selected value=\"-1\">Please Select Continent First</option>");

                            $("#searchEventError").fadeOut(200);
                            $("#searchEventError").fadeIn(200).html("<div class=\"alert-box error\">Something went wrong with the server request, please try again later</div>");

                        }
                    });

                    //console.log('A: Country DB: ' + response.eventData.countryId);
                    //$("#editEventCountries").change();

                    //console.log('A: Selected Country: ' + $("#editEventCountries").val());


                    //console.log('A: Selected City: ' + $("#editEventCities").val());

                    //$('#editEventModal').dialog( "open" );
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){            
                    /* log the error to the console */
                    console.log(
                        "The following error occured: " + 
                        textStatus, errorThrown
                    );
                },
                complete: function(){

                }
            });
        }
        break;
        default:
            alert("Don't know what to do but id is "+id);
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok, will give it a try, thanks! I'll post the results later on :)

Comment: Hum... been checking this out in more detail. I think you were looking at the wrong place.

These dynamic boxes work for other stuff.

The issue here is: I click a line on a table and press edit. I want to update the record. And the record does have a location based on continent, country and city.

So, the edit form also has these dynamic drop-downs.

The issue is: continent for that record coming from the DB comes just fine. I use the val() method to set the drop-down in the form using the record I got.

But then it fails to fetch the country data. And so on.

Comment: What I mean is: the only practical difference between what you wrote and what I wrote is calling the trigger for change from one box to the other.

Comment: @Pintolaranja, This question hasn't gotten any more answers, so I think it's just you and me.  :)  Yours was a long answer and I want to read it carefully, so it may take a bit for a reply.  In the mean time, is this code someplace I can take a look at the actual site? I understand if you can't for privacy reasons.  Also, this may be something better handled in chat, otherwise we're going to trigger this as a community wiki question and that won't help.  It looks like you're in Europe.  If possible, when could I get online with you to iron this out?

Comment: Hi, this is something ongoing, but ok, you can take a peek at the site here: http://wedoitforfun.org/wazzup

I understood now that using .val() to set some select's option will not trigger the change event. This is ok.

But even if I do trigger change after setting the value, right after it is coming out empty, which means I cannot set the option properly for the next select list. (there is some logging being done for the console in there)

And I wonder what is the relation if this not working with me doing this processing inside an ajax success callback...

Answer (score 1):

What I mean is: it seems like the only practical difference between what you wrote and what I wrote is explicitly calling the trigger for change from one box to the other.

On the other hand, I have something like this as well:

```
    $("#editEventContinents").change(function(){ // continents on change
    return loadCountries("#editEventContinents", "#editEventCountries", "#editEventCities");
});

$("#editEventCountries").change(function(){ // countries on change
    return loadCities("#editEventCountries", "#editEventCities");
});
```

Which means, it does pretty much the same, right?

My issue is really when processing a table row in order to get it edited and consequently updated. That is where the drop-downs will fail.

Using something like

```
 loadContinents("#editEventContinents");
 $("#editEventContinents").val(response.eventData.continentId);
```

Will not trigger the change event on the continent drop-down box. And if I do it explicitely the result is also not nice, loading the countries still does not identify the selected object. Which means the query string will go empty to the backend and then all the mess happens.